# Get values of one property to list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Group` property in `Profile`, it's added in `webconfig`

```
<properties>
    //...
    <add name="Group" />
    //...
</properties>
```

I'd like to get all values from all users that were entered in that property to a list.
How to do that?

Comment: AFAIK the profile isn't designed to do this.  You can always query the database directly but it's a real hassle.

Comment: Ok. So then if I make a model `Groups` with `ID` and `Name` how to connect that to `Users`. I'm using the default Membership Provider. Basically it should allow me to filter users by that group. Kind of like `Roles` but I can't use Roles :(

Comment: So this will end up being a hassle due to how they store the profile data in the db.  You'll probably end up having to write a stored procedure or view or something.  I'll see if I can give you a more detailed answer later.

Comment: Hey @user1407758. Sorry I forgot to do this last night.  I just went on vacation for the long weekend.  I'll take a look at this when I get back.  In the meantime, if you take a look at the profile tables you should be able to identify how the profile property values are stored (as xml).  You'll probably be best off writing a stored procedure or something to parse the xml and give you the values that you're looking for.